# How to grid data points onto a shapefile (grid)?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, raster

So I am working with a shapefile and a csv file of data points. I have used a raster function to convert the shapefile to a grid based on latitudes/longitudes. Now I need to put data points onto the same grid so that I can see where they fall in comparison to the "shape" produced by the other file. I have opened the csv file using the below code, and removed where the latitude/longitudes are null and made two new numpy arrays of lat/lons. But now I am confused about the next step, so if anyone has done anything similar, how should I proceed?

x = list(csv.reader(open(places,'rb'),delimiter=','))

List1 = zip(*x)

dataDict1 = {}

for column in List1:

```
dataDict1[col[0]] = col[1:]
```

lats =  np.array(dataDict1['Latitude'])

lons =  np.array(dataDict1['Longitude'])